# How to install cross compiler (on ubuntu 12.04 LTS) for microprocessor SA1100?

Tags: linux, gcc, ubuntu, compiler-construction, arm

Can someone please tell me how to install the cross compiler (programming language C) for the SA1100 microprocessor? I have ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I´m a complete noob to Linux, I just installed Ubuntu yesterday. I need a special variant of the GCC compiler that is named "arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc" but don know how to do it.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Did you try `apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` or `apt-get install gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi`? I also strongly recommend being able to compile an ordinary C program for your Linux system (i.e. learn the basics of `gcc`, `make` ... commands and how to use some editor like `emacs` or `gedit` ...) and the cross compiler you want also depends upon the system running on your SA1100 hardware board.

Comment: I do know how to compile an ordinary C program. That was `gcc -o hello hello.c`. I already tried `apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` and installed but cross compiling still doesn´t work. I want to cross compile the programs  with (for example) `arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -O2 -Wall -o hello hello.c` but it tells me the command couldn be found. Can you also tell me what `make` is for? Thank you, I appreciate your help!

Comment: You should actually use `gcc -Wall -g hello.c -o hello` ; About `make`, read http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html and use the `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc`  program as your cross-compiler

Comment: Additional hint, use `dpkg -L gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi` to learn about the files installed by package `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You may want to post an answer.

Comment: I know use arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -O2 -Wall -o hello hello.c to cross compile. Will this program work on an Intel-SA1100 microprocessor?

Comment: It needs at least a Linux kernel and an libc to run

Comment: Ok, yeah of course. I´m sending the files by using `minicom` (serial). I now understand. Thank you for the help! :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/250696/cross-compile-for-arm

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As I told in comments, try

```
apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

or

```
apt-get install gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

I also strongly recommend being able to compile an ordinary C program for your Linux system (i.e. learn the basics of `gcc`, `make` ... commands and how to use some editor like `emacs` or `gedit` ...) and the cross compiler you want also depends upon the system running on your SA1100 hardware board.  Don't forget to pass `-Wall` to any GCC compilation. You probably want to be able to debug your program (pass `-g` to GCC at compilation, and use the `gdb` debugger). When your program is running well, compile it with `-O2` to ask GCC to optimize its machine code.

Learn to use GNU `make` -e.g. to write `Makefile`-s- by reading its [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) and use the `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc` as the cross-compiler program. (You might want to use `remake` to debug your `Makefile`-s when `make` does not help enough)

You can get the list of files installed with a package with e.g. `dpkg -L gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi`

A cross compiled program executable for ARM very probably needs a Linux kernel with some `libc` (or link it statically) at least on the ARM motherboard, and you need some way to transmit the binary program from the Linux desktop to the ARM hardware.

Answer (score 5):

Add the ppa: https://launchpad.net/gcc-arm-embedded
The source codes for both are same. Currently supports Ubuntu 10.04/12.04/13.04/13.10/14.04 32 and 64 bit.

Detailed explanations to Launchpad PPA can be found at https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/. That website explains how a PPA is set up and how to add existing PPA and install software from it.

Here are quick steps to install toolchain from this PPA on Ubuntu before 14.04. Open a terminal and type :

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:terry.guo/gcc-arm-embedded`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-none-eabi`

To remove installed toolchain, just do :

`sudo apt-get remove gcc-arm-none-eabi`

To update the toolchain, just repeat step 2 and 3.